# Having trouple listening for messages in homemade C/C++ websocket implementation

Tags: c++, c, sockets, websocket, posix

So I am for the moment implementing a websocket in C/C++, and after a lot of mess I got the handshake to work (it was a whitespace error..). Anyways, now I'm lost on how to keep listening for messages after the handshake is established, I'm learning as I go, so it's a bit of a mess, but I'll answer any questions about the code, of course. This is what I have right now:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
//cpp                                                                                                       
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include "include/base64.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    time_t ticks;

    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(8080);

    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    listen(listenfd, 8080);
    bool ws = false;
    while(1)
    {
        int res = 0;
        if(ws){
            while(true){
                char buffer_ws[1400];
                res = recv(listenfd, buffer_ws, 1400, 0);
                if(res > 0)
                    std::cout << "Data!" << std::endl;
                sleep(1);
            }
        }
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);

        std::cout << "connfd = " << connfd << std::endl;

        char buffer[1400];

        read(connfd, buffer, 1400);

        std::string buf(buffer);
        std::cout << buf << std::endl;

        std::string reply;

        ws = strstr(buffer, "Upgrade: websocket");
        if(ws){ // if websocket handshake. This works                                                       
            std::cout << "<websocket>" << std::endl;
            std::string key = buf.substr(buf.find("Sec-WebSocket-Key") + 19,
                                buf.substr(buf.find("Sec-WebSocket-Key")).find("\n") - 20);

            std::cout << "key = " << key << std::endl;
            key.append("258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11");
            std::cout << "key = " << key << " length = " << key.length() << std::endl;
            unsigned char const* hash = SHA1(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(key.c_str()), key.lengt\
h(), nullptr);
            std::string b64 = base64_encode(hash, 20);
            std::cout << "b64 = " << b64 << std::endl;

            reply =
                "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n"
                "Upgrade: websocket\r\n"
                "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
                "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + b64 + "\r\n\r\n";
        }else{
            std::cout << "<other>" << std::endl;
            reply =
                "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n"
                "\n<script>var ws = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.10.117:8080');\n"
                "ws.addEventListener('open',function(event){"
                "\n\tconsole.log('open!!');\n\tws.send('yo bro!');\n});\n"
                "var sendmessage = function(){console.log('click');ws.send('test123');};</script>"
                "<input type=\"text\"><button onclick=\"sendmessage()\">send</button>";
        }
        send(connfd, reply.c_str(), reply.size(), 0);
        close(connfd);
        sleep(1);
     }
}
```

Right now I just don't receive anything when I try to send from the client websocket.

Comment: Looks like a giant code dump. Where's the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: After sending `Switching Protocols`, you shall continue to `read` from the socket `connfd` instead of closing it.

Comment: @MrEricSir Sorry, this is the whole system, and taking a smaller piece out of context would leave many questions about what the variables are and such. I could have dropped the includes, though. I'll remember for my next post.

Comment: @Marian So I make a loop that lasts until disconnection from client, right? If so, I need to make it a separate thread to serve more clients, am I getting this right?

Comment: @Jontahan It depends on your solution, you can spawn a new thread for each connection reading websocket messages or use some other mechanism, `select` for example.

Comment: If you don't know how to do this, I'm curious why you don't just get a library that has fully implemented the whole webSocket protocol (including protocol variants) and then you can spend more time on your real app logic than writing your own plumping.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm not doing this because I'm in a dire need of a websocket server, but rather because I learn a bunch of stuff in the process of writing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jontahan,

I think you're off to a great start and tons of fun with this project - but this isn't a small endeavor and there's a lot to learn and fix as you go.

There are a few issues of design in your code that:

1. Block you from progressing to the next stage (listening to messages while accepting new connections); and
2. Introduce meaningful security vulnerabilities that might result in DoS (denial of service).

For example, after blocking on `accept` (during which, you can't read incoming client messages), you go ahead and block on `read`, waiting for the HTTP request (again, your code is waiting for a network event while it might have better things to do).

This behavior blocks your code from performing tasks, since your code is waiting for IO (`accept` / `read`) while other events might be happening concurrently (i.e., what if a websocket message arrives while your code is busy waiting on `accept` for the last 10 minutes?).

In addition, this behavior introduces a security vulnerability related to slow clients (i.e., clients with bad reception or malicious attackers). For example, what if the HTTP request takes a whole minute to arrive? What if it arrives defragmented? What if it arrived one line at a time? what if it arrived one letter at a time?

...

Your code is a great start for testing the handshake, but the core design should be reconsidered before the code can be used as an actual server.

One solution - often employed for small servers - is to use a thread-per-connection design, so after `accept` a new thread is spawned and it's in charge on handling the connection (it blocks on `read` without disrupting other threads).

However, this solution is sub-optimal and introduces a number of minor security risks (every design has security risks, it's about choosing the minimal risk possible).

Another solution, as implemented by some of the best (`nginx` / `node.js`) is to use an "evented" design with a single thread. This is sometimes refered to as a "reactor" design.

This design is by far one of the best, but it does suffer from other concerns and it requires a lot of attention in the code, so slow running tasks / functions don't grind the whole server to a halt.

This design is often implemented using `kqueue`, `epoll` or (for lack of a better choice) `poll` / `select`

In psedo-code, it might look like this:

```
void defer_task(void (*func((void *)), void * arg) {
  // place task in queue
}

void run_tasks() {
  while (queue->not_empty()) {
    task = grab_oldest_task();
    task.func(task.arg);
  }
}

void task_listen(void * data) {
  // open listening socket
}

void task_poll(void * _) {
  // poll existing clients and listening sockets
  // probably using `kqueue`/`epoll`/`poll`/`select`
  defer_task(task_ondata, (void*)fd);
  // finish with rescheduling the poll task
  defer_task(task_poll, NULL);
}

void task_ondata(void * data) {
  int fd = (intptr_t)data;
  // handle `accept` / `read` making sure all sockets are non-blocking
}

int main(void) {
  defer_task(task_listen, NULL);
  defer_task(task_poll, NULL);
  run_tasks();
}
```

Here's an example for an task scheduling system I wrote... it wasn't tested in production, but it might clarify what I meant about the `defer_task`:

```
/* *****************************************************************************
API declarations - should be moved to a separate .h file.
***************************************************************************** */

/** Defer an execution of a function for later. Returns -1 on error.*/
int defer(void (*func)(void *), void *arg);

/** Performs all deferred functions until the queue had been depleated. */
void defer_perform(void);

/** returns true if there are deferred functions waiting for execution. */
int defer_has_queue(void);

/* *****************************************************************************
Compile time settings
***************************************************************************** */

#ifndef DEFER_QUEUE_BUFFER
#define DEFER_QUEUE_BUFFER 1024
#endif


/* *****************************************************************************
spinlock / sync for tasks
***************************************************************************** */
#if defined(__unix__) || defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__linux__)
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <time.h>
#endif /* _GNU_SOURCE */
#include <stdlib.h>

/* manage the way threads "wait" for the lock to release */
#if defined(__unix__) || defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__linux__)
/* nanosleep seems to be the most effective and efficient reschedule */
#define defer_nanosleep(length)                                                \
  {                                                                            \
    static const struct timespec tm = {.tv_nsec = length};                     \
    nanosleep(&tm, NULL);                                                      \
  }
#define reschedule_thread() defer_nanosleep(1)
#define throttle_thread() defer_nanosleep(8388608UL)

#else /* no effective rescheduling, just spin... */
#define reschedule_thread()
#define throttle_thread()
#endif

/** locks use a single byte */
typedef volatile unsigned char spn_lock_i;
/** The initail value of an unlocked spinlock. */
#define SPN_LOCK_INIT 0

/* Select the correct compiler builtin method. */
#if defined(__has_builtin)
#if __has_builtin(__sync_swap)
#define SPN_LOCK_BUILTIN(...) __sync_swap(__VA_ARGS__)
#elif __has_builtin(__sync_fetch_and_or)
#define SPN_LOCK_BUILTIN(...) __sync_fetch_and_or(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#error Required builtin "__sync_swap" or "__sync_fetch_and_or" missing from compiler.
#endif /* defined(__has_builtin) */
#elif __GNUC__ > 3
#define SPN_LOCK_BUILTIN(...) __sync_fetch_and_or(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#error Required builtin "__sync_swap" or "__sync_fetch_and_or" not found.
#endif

/** returns 1 and 0 if the lock was successfully aquired (TRUE == FAIL). */
static inline int spn_trylock(spn_lock_i *lock) {
  return SPN_LOCK_BUILTIN(lock, 1);
}

/** Releases a lock. */
static inline __attribute__((unused)) void spn_unlock(spn_lock_i *lock) {
  __asm__ volatile("" ::: "memory");
  *lock = 0;
}
/** returns a lock's state (non 0 == Busy). */
static inline __attribute__((unused)) int spn_is_locked(spn_lock_i *lock) {
  __asm__ volatile("" ::: "memory");
  return *lock;
}
/** Busy waits for the lock. */
static inline __attribute__((unused)) void spn_lock(spn_lock_i *lock) {
  while (spn_trylock(lock)) {
    reschedule_thread();
  }
}

/* *****************************************************************************
Data Structures
***************************************************************************** */

typedef struct {
  void (*func)(void *);
  void *arg;
} task_s;

typedef struct task_node_s {
  task_s task;
  struct task_node_s *next;
} task_node_s;

static task_node_s tasks_buffer[DEFER_QUEUE_BUFFER];

static struct {
  task_node_s *first;
  task_node_s **last;
  task_node_s *pool;
  spn_lock_i lock;
  unsigned char initialized;
} deferred = {.first = NULL,
              .last = &deferred.first,
              .pool = NULL,
              .lock = 0,
              .initialized = 0};

/* *****************************************************************************
API
***************************************************************************** */

/** Defer an execution of a function for later. */
int defer(void (*func)(void *), void *arg) {
  if (!func)
    return -1;
  task_node_s *task;
  spn_lock(&deferred.lock);
  if (deferred.pool) {
    task = deferred.pool;
    deferred.pool = deferred.pool->next;
  } else if (deferred.initialized) {
    task = malloc(sizeof(task_node_s));
    if (!task)
      goto error;
  } else { /* lazy initialization of task buffer */
    deferred.initialized = 1;
    task = tasks_buffer;
    deferred.pool = tasks_buffer + 1;
    for (size_t i = 2; i < DEFER_QUEUE_BUFFER; i++) {
      tasks_buffer[i - 1].next = tasks_buffer + i;
    }
  }
  *deferred.last = task;
  deferred.last = &task->next;
  task->task.func = func;
  task->task.arg = arg;
  task->next = NULL;
  spn_unlock(&deferred.lock);
  return 0;
error:
  spn_unlock(&deferred.lock);
  return -1;
}

/** Performs all deferred functions until the queue had been depleted. */
void defer_perform(void) {
  task_node_s *tmp;
  task_s task;
restart:
  spn_lock(&deferred.lock);
  tmp = deferred.first;
  if (tmp) {
    deferred.first = tmp->next;
    if (!deferred.first)
      deferred.last = &deferred.first;
    task = tmp->task;
    if (tmp <= tasks_buffer + (DEFER_QUEUE_BUFFER - 1) && tmp >= tasks_buffer) {
      tmp->next = deferred.pool;
      deferred.pool = tmp;
    } else {
      free(tmp);
    }
    spn_unlock(&deferred.lock);
    task.func(task.arg);
    goto restart;
  } else
    spn_unlock(&deferred.lock);
}

/** returns true if there are deferred functions waiting for execution. */
int defer_has_queue(void) { return deferred.first != NULL; }
```